# Computer crashes on wakeup from standby and multi colors flash on screen.

Tags: windows, display, wake-up

I booted my desktop computer from Standby Mode and the monitor started flickering all different colors of the rainbow.  I filmed it with this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-uMZhmyqAY0

It happens after I press the power button from Standby Mode.

If I force shut down the computer, then boot it up again, it works correctly.  This problem only happens once in a while.

How do I debug such a problem?

Comment: Multiple possible reasons. MOst likely, your graphics card wasn't able to wake up from sleep - happens, and could be a driver issue. DO you know which power level your PC was at (S1-S5)?

Comment: I do not. No idea what it even is.

Comment: Well, if the problem is reproducible, you better do some reading ;) Basics: COmputer has multiple power states. The lower the number, the more energy it uses. S0 is on, S5 is "almost off, except network for wake-on-lan". Hibernate state used by windows is S4, Standby usually uses S2 or S3. This is where the problem might be: Some devices, and a few graphics cards amongst them, don't support S3 very well. BUt: this doesn't have to be the issue. There is jut no way to tell, given how little info we got. Best stay with @ultrasawblade's suggestions first.

Comment: This is the first time I've ever witnessed (even secondhand) an actual "snow crash" of a computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Johannes H. assessment.

- Make sure your video drivers are the latest version.
- Make sure your chipset drivers are the latest version.
- Make sure your BIOS is updated to the latest version.

If this continues to happen, you may have

- bad RAM
- a bad GPU
- a bad motherboard

which would need to be replaced.

Comment: ALso, you might want to chekc if your BIOS/UEFI has an option to select power saving levels used for standby. If so (and the problem is reproducible when waking up form standby), you might want to try other options there. Another thing to try (again: if the problem persists) is switchign the PSU.
If the problem does not happen again, just ignore it. Most likely there was no harm done, such things sometimes just happen under certain rare and very special circumstances that you won't ever be able to reproduce.